# boto3: How to interract with DigitalOcean S3 Spaces when CDN is enabled

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, digital-ocean, cdn

I'm working with DigitalOcean Spaces (S3 storage protocol) which has enabled [CDN](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/enable-cdn/).

Any file on s3 can be accessed via direct URL in the given form:

```
https://my-bucket.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/<file_key>
```

If CDN **is enabled**, the file can be accessed via additional CDN URL:

```
https://my-bucket.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/<file_key>
```

where `fra1` is a **region_name**.

When I'm using `boto3` SDK for Python, the file URL is the following (generated by boto3):

```
https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-bucket/<file_key>
# just note that bucket name is no more a domain part!
```

This format also works fine.

But, if CDN is enabled - file url causes an error:

```
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:  https://fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-bucket/<file_key>
```

assuming the endpoint_url was changed from

`default_endpoint=https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com`

to

`default_endpoint=https://fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com`

How to connect to CDN with proper URL without getting an error?
And why boto3 uses different URL format? Is any workaround can be applied in this case?

**code:**

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                            region_name=s3_configs['default_region'],
                            endpoint_url=s3_configs['default_endpoint'],
                            aws_access_key_id=s3_configs['bucket_access_key'],
                            aws_secret_access_key=s3_configs['bucket_secret_key'])

s3_client.download_file(bucket_name,key,local_filepath)
```

boto3 [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/) for DigitalOcean Spaces.

**Here is what I've also tried but It didn't work:**

- Generate [presigned url's](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)

**UPDATE**
Based on @Amit Singh's answer:

As I mentioned before, I've already tried this trick with presigned URLs.
I've got Urls like this

```
https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/<my-bucket>/interiors/uploaded/images/07IRgHJ2PFhVqVrJDCIpzhghqe4TwK1cSSUXaC4T.jpeg?<presigned-url-params>
```

The bucket name appears after endpoint. I had to move It to domain-level manually:

```
https://<my-bucket>.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/interiors/uploaded/images/07IRgHJ2PFhVqVrJDCIpzhghqe4TwK1cSSUXaC4T.jpeg?<presigned-url-params>
```

With this URL I can now connect to Digital ocean, but another arror occures:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<RequestId>tx00000000000008dfdbc88-006005347c-604235a-fra1a</RequestId>
<HostId>604235a-fra1a-fra1</HostId>
</Error>
```

As a workaround I've tired to use signature `s3v4`:

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                                 region_name=configs['default_region'],
                                 endpoint_url=configs['default_endpoint'],
                                 aws_access_key_id=configs['bucket_access_key'],
                                 aws_secret_access_key=configs['bucket_secret_key'],
                                 config= boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

but It still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Amit Singh's answer, I've made an additional research of this issue.

Answers that helped me were found [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1644#issuecomment-701864589) and [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1644#issuecomment-730409713).

To make boto3 presigned URLs work, I've made the following update to `client` and `generate_presigned_url()` params.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         region_name=configs['default_region'],
                         endpoint_url=configs['default_endpoint'],
                         aws_access_key_id=configs['bucket_access_key'],
                         aws_secret_access_key=configs['bucket_secret_key'],
                         config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4', retries={
                             'max_attempts': 10,
                             'mode': 'standard'
                         },
                         s3={'addressing_style': "virtual"}, ))
...

response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                            Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                    'Key': object_name},
                                            ExpiresIn=3600,
                                            HttpMethod=None
                                            )
```

After that, `.cdn` domain part shoud be added after region name.

Answer (score 6):

`boto3` is a client library for Amazon S3 and not Digital Ocean Spaces. So, `boto3` will not recognize the CDN URL `fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com` since it is provided by Digital Ocean and the URL with CDN is not one of the supported URI patterns. I don't fully understand how CDNs work internally, so my guess is there might be challenges with implementing this redirection to correct URL.

Now that that's clear, let's see how we can get a pre-signed CDN URL. Suppose, your CDN URL is `https://fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com` and your space name is `my-space`. We want to get a pre-signed URL for an object `my-example-object` stored in the space.

```py
import os
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

# Initialize the client
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('s3',
                        region_name='fra1',
                        endpoint_url='https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com', # Remove `.cdn` from the URL
                        aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('SPACES_KEY'),
                        aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('SPACES_SECRET'),
                        config=Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'}))

# Get a presigned URL for object 
url = client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                                    Params={'Bucket': 'my-space',
                                            'Key': 'my-example-object'},
                                    ExpiresIn=300)

print(url)
```

The pre-signed URL will look something like :

```html
https://my-space.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-example-object?AWSAccessKeyId=EXAMPLE7UQOTHDTF3GK4&Content-Type=text&Expires=1580419378&Signature=YIXPlynk4BALXE6fH7vqbnwjSEw%3D
```

Add the `cdn` in between either manually or programmatically, in case you need to so that your final URL will become:

```html
https://my-space.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-example-object?AWSAccessKeyId=EXAMPLE7UQOTHDTF3GK4&Content-Type=text&Expires=1580419378&Signature=YIXPlynk4BALXE6fH7vqbnwjSEw%3D
```

This is your CDN URL.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed answer.
Please, check the UPDATE section in my question above.
I've tried your suggestion, bug there Is another issue with signatures.

Comment: @arturkuchynski Updated my answer for the URL change. You can generate it by simply passing `config=Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'})` param to your S3 client.